# Special case to grab the headers for a DictReader in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, data-structures

Normally the [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) will use the first line of a .csv file as the column headers, i.e. the keys to the dictionary:

```
If the fieldnames parameter is omitted, the values in the first row of the csvfile will be used as the fieldnames.
```

However, I am faced with something like this for my first line:

`#Format: header1  header2 header3` ...etc.

The `#Format:` needs to be skipped, as it is not a column header. I could do something like:

```
column_headers = ['header1', 'header2', 'header3']
reader = csv.dictReader(my_file, delimiter='\t', fieldnames=column_headers)
```

But I would rather have the DictReader handle this for two reason.

1. There are a lot of columns
2. The column names may change over time, and this is a quarterly-run process.

Is there some way to have the DictReader still use the first line as the column headers, but skip that first `#Format:` word? Or really any word that starts with a `#` would probably suffice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `DictReader` wraps an open file, you could read the first line of the file, parse the headers from there (`headers = my_file.readline().split(delimiter)[1:]`, or something like that), and then pass them to `DictReader()` as the `fieldnames` argument. The `DictReader` constructor does not reset the file, so you don't have to worry about it reading in the header list after you've parsed that.

Comment: Nice I like this. I was thinking I could stick a `lambda()` in there somewhere, but this is more straight-forward and probably a bit cleaner also, ty.